# phpmyadmin delete text between [somemark]text[/somemark]

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have lot of post in wp database and need to clear some rest of code from the last editor.

First I need to clear text between

```
[somemark]text[/somemark]
```

Then its easy to delete marks. text is different in every post, marks are constant

Answer (score 0):

With WP-CLI:

```
$ wp search-replace '(\[somemark\][^\[]+\[\/somemark\])' '' --regex
```